# App crashed on ipad simulator 4.3 only

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, ios4, ios-simulator

Hi there my app crashed only on iPad simulator 4.3.  The app run fine in the iPad simulator 5.0, iPhone simulator 4.3 and iPhone simulator 5.0.    Any idea what might be causing this?
The following is the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "HomeViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

0   CoreFoundation                      0x0130b5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0145f313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x012c3ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x012c3e6a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   UIKit                               0x0060f709 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 295
    5   UIKit                               0x0060d134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    6   UIKit                               0x0060d00e -[UIViewController view] + 56
    7   UIKit                               0x0060b7f5 -[UIViewController nextResponder] + 34
    8   UIKit                               0x0062c4a6 -[UIResponder _containsResponder:] + 41
    9   UIKit                               0x00616c4e -[UINavigationController defaultFirstResponder] + 80
    10  UIKit                               0x0062b647 -[UIResponder(Internal) _deepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 42
    11  UIKit                               0x0062b663 -[UIResponder(Internal) _deepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 70
    12  UIKit                               0x0062b406 -[UIResponder(Internal) _promoteDeepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 42
    13  sightwords                          0x00001ddb -[sightwordsAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 395
    14  UIKit                               0x0055dc89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    15  UIKit                               0x0055fd88 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
    16  UIKit                               0x0056a617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    17  UIKit                               0x00562abf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    18  UIKit                               0x00567f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x017e5992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x012ec944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0124ccf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01249f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01249840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x01249761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    25  UIKit                               0x0055f7d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    26  UIKit                               0x0056bc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    27  sightwords                          0x00001c19 main + 121
    28  sightwords                          0x00001b95 start + 53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turned out, this error is only happening in ipad 4.3 simulator.  actualy ipad 4.3 device run just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In your nib, you need to set the File Owner class to HomeViewController, and then connect the top-level view to the File Owner's `view` outlet.

Comment: if i don't have the file owner's class set, wouldn't that make it crash on iPad simulator 5.o and iPhone simulator 4.3 and 5.0?

Comment: I just checked, it's definitely set.

Comment: Apparently not, if my suggestion works...  Normally you'd have separate nibs for iPhone and iPad.  Maybe you did it properly in the iPhone nib, and maybe UIViewController is smarter in iOS 5.  Or maybe my suggestion was incorrect.

Comment: When you say it's set, do you mean the file owner class, or the file owner view outlet, or both?  In the iPad nib?

Comment: I only have 1 nib.  I don't have a separate one for iPad.

Comment: I'm able to confirm that the app doesn't crash on an actual ipad device running iOS 5.  Still looking for ipad runnign iOS 4.3 to check.  But as of right now. Its still crashing in iOS 4.3 simulator